# getInputStream() with symbols

Tags: java, json

So i am trying to lookup item prices from items in csgo. It works fine for skin names without stattrack but when i am to lookup prices for those skins i have to use the "™" symbol and i think it makes the InputStreamReader unable somehow. If i copy the generated url to my browser it gets the result just fine.

The url: http://api.csgo.steamlytics.xyz/v1/prices/StatTrak™%20M4a1-s%20%7C%20golden%20coil%20%28Factory%20New%29?pretty=1&source=0&from=1week&key=****

The part of the code that fails:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://api.csgo.steamlytics.xyz/v1/prices/"+ name +"?pretty=1&source=0&from=1week&key="+key);
        System.out.println("Looking up: " + url);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

The error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
http://api.csgo.steamlytics.xyz/v1/prices/StatTrak™%20M4a1-s%20%7C%20golden%20coil%20%28Factory%20New%29?pretty=1&source=0&from=1week&key=****

```
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at tradeup.Main.getPrice(Main.java:21)
at tradeup.Main.updateDB(Main.java:75)
at tradeup.Main.main(Main.java:105)
```

Comment: First open a connection, then open an input stream to it. Use `HttpUrlConnection` to open a connection

Comment: Thanks i tried it but i still get the same error :/

Comment: What happens when you open that URL in a browser (using a valid key)?

Comment: I get this result:
{
  "success": true,
    "median_price": "280.49",
    "median_net_price": "243.91",
    "average_price": "275.40",
    "average_net_price": "239.48",
    "lowest_price": "253.00",
    "lowest_net_price": "220.00",
    "highest_price": "285.00",
    "highest_net_price": "247.83",
    "mean_absolute_deviation": "8.41",
    "deviation_percentage": 0.030537400145243,
    "volume": 7,
    "first_seen": 1444519687
}